# vb.Net and MySQL slow retrieving of records

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good day all!

I'm having issues in retrieving records with Vb.net and MySQL, it took awhile to display/retrieve a specific information which is stored in 2 tables (Order_Details and Result_Details) for every Order there are 20-26 Results.

My current stored data is (Order_Details = 8,839 and Result_Details = 175,418) approximately 250k of data. I'm also running the whole system in Intel Core i5 with 8gb of RAM.

This should've been a problem because when I open Navicat it only take a split sec to display all data.

Now, my question is how can I optimized my querying to gain maximum performance, I know the data is just a fraction of what MySQL can store and it should not behave like this.

I would like to ask for your opinion, tips and tricks on how to optimized my query statements.

Retrieving from Database to OrderList.

```
Public Sub LoadRecords()
        Try
            lvList.ListViewItemSorter = New MyComparer
            lvList.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            lvList.Sort()

            LoadRecordsOnLVSQL(lvList, "SELECT `id`, `status`, `sample_id`, `patient_id`, `patient_name`, `test`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y'), `time`, `dt_released` FROM `order` ORDER BY `id` DESC", 8)

            For x As Integer = 0 To lvList.Items.Count - 1 Step 1
                lvList.Items(x).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                If lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = "Ordered" Then
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.White
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.White
                ElseIf lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = "Result Received" Then
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.Yellow
                ElseIf lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = "Printed" Then
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.Green
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.White
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.Green
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = "Released" Then
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.Green
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.White
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.Green
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = "Accepted" Then
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.HotPink
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.White
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.HotPink
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = "Rejected" Then
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.Crimson
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.White
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.Crimson
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                Else
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).BackColor = Color.DarkGray
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(0).ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.DarkGray
                    lvList.Items(x).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Retrieving Results Based on Order

```
Private Sub LoadTest()
    'On Error Resume Next
    rs.Parameters.Clear()
    rs.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainID", mainID)

    dtResult.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 9)
    dtResult.ForeColor = Color.Black
    dtResult.Rows.Clear()
    dtResult.ColumnCount = 14
    dtResult.Columns(1).Name = "Test Name"
    dtResult.Columns(2).Name = "Flag"
    dtResult.Columns(3).Name = "Result"
    dtResult.Columns(4).Name = "S.I. Unit"
    dtResult.Columns(5).Name = "Normal Range"
    dtResult.Columns(6).Name = "Result"
    dtResult.Columns(7).Name = "Conv. Unit"
    dtResult.Columns(8).Name = "Normal Range"
    dtResult.Columns(9).Name = "S.I."
    dtResult.Columns(10).Name = "Conv."
    dtResult.Columns(11).Name = "Date"
    dtResult.Columns(12).Name = "Test Code"
    dtResult.Columns(13).Name = "ID"

    dtResult.Columns(1).Width = 150
    dtResult.Columns(2).Width = 50
    dtResult.Columns(3).Width = 50
    dtResult.Columns(4).Width = 120
    dtResult.Columns(5).Width = 120
    dtResult.Columns(6).Width = 50
    dtResult.Columns(7).Width = 120
    dtResult.Columns(8).Width = 120
    dtResult.Columns(9).Width = 50
    dtResult.Columns(10).Width = 50
    dtResult.Columns(11).Width = 100
    dtResult.Columns(12).Width = 100
    dtResult.Columns(12).Width = 100

    dtResult.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(3).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(4).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(5).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(6).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(7).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(8).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(9).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(10).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(11).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    dtResult.Columns(12).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

    Connect()
    rs.Connection = conn
    rs.CommandText = "SELECT `universal_id`, `flag`, `measurement`, `units`, `reference_range`, `value_conv`, `unit_conv`, `ref_conv`, `test_code`, `id`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM `result` WHERE `sample_id` = @MainID ORDER BY `order_no`"
    reader = rs.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        Dim rows As Object() = New Object() {
            ImageList.Images(0),
            reader(0).ToString,
            reader(1).ToString,
            reader(2).ToString,
            reader(3).ToString,
            reader(4).ToString,
            reader(5).ToString,
            reader(6).ToString,
            reader(7).ToString,
            "",
            "",
            "",
            reader(8).ToString,
            reader(9).ToString
            }
        dtResult.Rows.Add(rows)
    End While
    Disconnect()

    LoadRangeAndValues()
End Sub
Private Sub LoadRangeAndValues()
        For x As Integer = 0 To Me.dtResult.RowCount - 1 Step 1
            Dim RANGE As String = ""
            Dim RANGE_CONVENTIONAL As String = ""
            Dim FLAG As String = ""
            Dim ConvertionFactor As Double

            rs.Parameters.Clear()
            rs.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patient_id", txtPatientID.Text)
            rs.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestCode", dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(12).Value)

            Connect()
            rs.Connection = conn
            rs.CommandText = "SELECT `universal_id`, `measurement`, `value_conv`, `test_code`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM `result` WHERE (`patient_id` LIKE @patient_id AND `test_code` LIKE @TestCode)"
            reader = rs.ExecuteReader
            reader.Read()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(9).Value = reader(1).ToString
                dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(10).Value = reader(2).ToString
                dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(11).Value = reader(4).ToString
            End If
            Disconnect()

            Connect()
            rs.Connection = conn
            rs.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT(`range`.low, '-', `range`.high) AS `range`, `test_code`, `low`, `high` FROM `range` WHERE `test_code` = @TestCode AND `classification` = '" & txtClass.Text & "' AND `sex` = '" & cboSex.Text & "' AND (`age_begin` <= '" & Me.txtAge.Text & "' AND `age_end` >= '" & Me.txtAge.Text & "')"
            reader = rs.ExecuteReader
            reader.Read()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                RANGE = reader("range").ToString
                If Not dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value = "" Then
                    If CDbl(dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value) < Val(reader("low").ToString) Then
                        FLAG = "L"
                    ElseIf CDbl(dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value) > Val(reader("high").ToString) Then
                        FLAG = "H"
                    Else
                        FLAG = ""
                    End If
                    Disconnect()
                    dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value = RANGE
                    dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = FLAG
                Else
                    Disconnect()
                    dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value = RANGE
                End If
            End If
            Disconnect()

            Connect()
            rs.Connection = conn
            rs.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT(`range_conventional`.low, '-', `range_conventional`.high) AS `range`, `test_code`, `low`, `high` FROM `range_conventional` WHERE `test_code` = @TestCode AND `classification` = '" & txtClass.Text & "' AND `sex` = '" & cboSex.Text & "' AND (`age_begin` <= '" & Me.txtAge.Text & "' AND `age_end` >= '" & Me.txtAge.Text & "')"
            reader = rs.ExecuteReader
            reader.Read()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                RANGE_CONVENTIONAL = reader("range").ToString
                If Not dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value = "" Then
                    Disconnect()
                    dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(8).Value = RANGE_CONVENTIONAL
                Else
                    Disconnect()
                    dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(8).Value = RANGE_CONVENTIONAL
                End If
            End If
            Disconnect()

            Connect()
            rs.Connection = conn
            rs.CommandText = "SELECT `convertion_factor` FROM `specimen` WHERE `test_code` LIKE @TestCode"
            reader = rs.ExecuteReader
            reader.Read()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                If Not dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value = "" Then
                    ConvertionFactor = reader(0).ToString
                    Disconnect()
                    dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value = Val(dtResult.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value) / ConvertionFactor
                Else
                    Disconnect()
                    ConvertionFactor = 0
                End If
            Else
                ConvertionFactor = 0
            End If
            Disconnect()
        Next
    End Sub
```

Best regards, 
Ardie

Comment: How can we tell you how to optimise something we've never seen?  If something you're doing doesn't work then you're doing it wrong.  We can't tell you what's wrong with it if you don't show it to us.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include the codes.

Comment: That code is doing much more than just get some data from MySQL.  The parts that are clear as to what is going on are not the fastest way to do that by any means.

Comment: Can you specify which part and can you give me some overview on how i can optimized it .

Answer (score 0):

According to your question I came to know you are working with bulk of data.I am not clear about your system configuration issue that you mentioned.I think your configuration is ok. In this situation,

I think you can think about bellow approaches.

```
1. Use sub process(Thread) or background worker to retrieve data from database with 
   your Main UI Thread.
2.Optimize database connection string by creating a single instance, which has been 
   opened and closed several time in your code.
```

Comment: Yes that's true, the system is handling a bunch of data which is slowing down the retrieving of data especially while working in network. I'm currently optimizing my codes and I figured out that this multiple Select * query is slowing the system.